# How to disable OOO replies when sent to a distribution list in Google Apps Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

We basically need a feature similar to this:

http://windowsitpro.com/outlook/outlook-preventing-out-office-responses-mailing-lists

or this:

http://exchangeservergeeks.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/auto-response-from-distribution-group-exchange-2007-and-2010/

We have some users with a OOO message set that are members of a distribution list, and we don't want their OOO replies going to the entire list. Is this possible? And if yes, how can we it be done?

Comment: Assume that people reading this question can't (or won't) follow those links. Please [edit] your question to include the information needed to answer it. Links rot, after all, and we want this question (and answers) to be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/25922?hl=en):

> Messages classified as spam and **messages addressed to a mailing list you subscribe to will not receive a vacation response**.

(Emphasis by me.)

Comment: That's how we expected things to work - but they didn't - so we ended up opening a bug report with Google, and it got fixed.